# JSON won't decode from string in PHP

Tags: php, json

Good evening,

This is probably a stupid question but I've been fiddling with this for a while now. I have a string coming from an AJAX call. To inspect the actual string that gets sent to my PHP from some JavaScript I put it into the result and spit it out in the front end. The string looks like this:

```
    count: "[{\"cartKey\":\"d9d4f495e875a2e075a1a4a6e1b9770f\",\"qty\":\"3\"}, 
    {\"cartKey\":\"67c6a1e7ce56d3d6fa748ab6d9af3fd7\",\"qty\":\"2\"}, 
    {\"cartKey\":\"f7177163c833dff4b38fc8d2872f1ec6\",\"qty\":\"32\"}]"
```

So! My problem is getting this to be an actual PHP array. If I do this:

```
$result['count'] = json_decode($updates, true);
```

inside my PHP, the result is 0.

Ignore the count name on the result. I'm just trying to turn the above string into an array of objects I can use in PHP rather than a JSON string.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So what is the actual content of `$updates`?

Comment: That's not a valid JSON string. You're better off trying to fix the client side than to adapt the server side to handle the broken input.

Comment: It is invalid JSON. Replace `'\"'` by `'"'`

Comment: Its not an invalid json. If you notice the whole string is inside double quotes, therefore any `"` in the json string has to be escaped i.e. `\"`

Comment: Yeah, I did wonder about the slashes. I have solved the problem now, but I did some research on the slashes and they are necessary, as you say, which I assume is why they are there.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I'm a birk.

The actual value of `$updates` was null, I think.

I have just solved my problem by not calling JSON.stringify on the data sent from the AJAX call.

The value now comes through and is actually decoded as if by magic within the PHP script.

Thanks for taking a look.

Ash